# RESTful service do not response with ajax call using localhost

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, rest

From my work gave me a   project  to finish with which I am having the following problem:

In solution there is web API and RESTful API in MVC
if I call directly Restful service it's responding 
if i make a test and put in home controller in web API HttpWebResponse it is responding
but the request is put in .js file and the code is

> ```
> return $.ajax({
>     type: 'GET',
>     url: serviceURL,
>     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>     dataType: "json",
>     data: urlParams,
>     crossDomain: true,
>     beforeSend: lazy(),
>     complete: complete()
> });
> ```

and this is failing with the following message e requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS
in webconfig everything is settled correctly
It is not working if I call REST API locally, if I call those which is on server it is working.
I read almost everything connected to that problem, but I am still stuck.

Comment: Replace http to https in url where you get this error.

Comment: nothing changes

Comment: may be a CORS issue. Do you have it enabled in your WebApiConfig.cs? i mean a call to HttpConfiguration.EnableCors();

Comment: thank you Shahbaz. It was not HttpConfiguration.EnableCors(); but your suggestion made me check well the IIS and handler  mapping there, which was problem